# Sort a tab delimited file based on column sort command bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I am trying to sort this file based on the fourth column. I want the file to reordered based on the values of the fourth column.

File:

```
2   1:103496792:A   0   103496792
3   1:103544434:A   0   103544434
4   1:103548497:A   0   103548497
1   1:10363487:T    0   10363487
```

I want it sorted like this:

```
1   1:10363487:T    0   10363487
2   1:103496792:A   0   103496792
3   1:103544434:A   0   103544434
4   1:103548497:A   0   103548497
```

I tried this command:

```
sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k 4,4 <filename>
```

But I get illegal variable name error. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To sort on the fourth column use just the `-k 4,4` selector.

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 4,4 <filename>
```

You might also want `-V` which sorts numbers more naturally. For example, yielding `1 2 10` rather than `1 10 2` (lexicographic order).

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 4,4 -V <filename>
```

If you're getting errors about the `$'\t'` then make sure your shell is bash. Perhaps you're missing `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script?

Comment: same error though.. illegal variable name. I dont know how to resolve it. I know the problem is with the $

Comment: Make sure you are using bash and not `#!/bin/sh` or `sh script`

Comment: Also, the `-t` option would be optional here, since the default column separator of "any whitespace" would suffice for your file.

Comment: Use "-n" to sort numerically.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have an errant `$` in your command.

Try:

```
sort -t\t -nk4
```

Comment: `$'..'` is bash syntax for expanding escape sequences. In this case it expands to a literal tab.

Comment: that helped but cant it order as 1 2 10 than 1 10 2 22??

Comment: That's what the `-n` flag should be doing (numeric sort).